# MySQL CONCAT not finding table with alias

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a fairly straight forward Query, that I am not understanding why `CONCAT` isn't working.

I am `JOINING` the tables `domains` `client_content` and `domain_status` and attempting to `insert into` `vhosts`.  All works as expected until I use `CONCAT` to combine `domain_status.status_directory` and `client_configuration.user_file`.  At this point are the aliases I assigned out of scope?

```
                      ----------------------------------------
domains               |  domain   |   enabled   |   status   |
                      ----------------------------------------

                      -------------------------------------
client_configuration  |   contractor_id   |   user_file   |
                      -------------------------------------

                      ---------------------------------
domain_status         |   id   |   status_directory   |
                      ---------------------------------

                      ------------------------------------------------------------
vhosts                |   site_name   |   directory   |   enabled   |   status   |
                      ------------------------------------------------------------


INSERT INTO vhosts (`site_name`, `directory`, `enabled`, `status`)
    SELECT d.domain, CONCAT(`s.status_directory`,'/',`c.user_file`), d.enabled, d.status  
    FROM domains d

    LEFT JOIN client_configuration c
        ON d.contractor_id = c.contractor_id
    LEFT JOIN domains_status s
        ON d.status = s.id
    WHERE d.domain = 'example.com';
```

From what I understand, I should be able to use `CONCAT` in this fashion, but I get a MySQL error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 's.status_directory' in 'field list'
```

If I can't use `CONCAT` like this .. What's the work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've surrounded the table alias with the same backquotes as the column name. Take the table alias out of those quotes. Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO vhosts 
(
  `site_name`, 
  `directory`, 
  `enabled`, 
  `status`
)
SELECT 
  d.domain, 
  CONCAT(s.`status_directory`,'/', c.`user_file`), 
  d.enabled, 
  d.status  
FROM domains d
LEFT JOIN client_configuration c
  ON d.contractor_id = c.contractor_id
LEFT JOIN domains_status s
  ON d.status = s.id
WHERE d.domain = 'example.com';
```

Comment: Well I am glad you see something as obvious when some of us don't see it that way!!  Good catch, thank you!

Comment: @Zak An extra pair of eyes is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes: `INSERT INTO vhosts (site_name, directory, enabled, status)
 SELECT d.domain, CONCAT(s.status_directory,'/',c.user_file) as statusUserFile, d.enabled, d.status 
 FROM domains d LEFT JOIN client_configuration c
 ON d.contractor_id = c.contractor_id
 LEFT JOIN domains_status s
 ON d.status = s.id
 WHERE d.domain = 'example.com';`